# C# efficient datastructure to store objects sorted by key with duplicate keys to fit given requirements

Tags: c#, sorting, data-structures, collections

I'm looking for the most efficient way to store a collection of objects sorted by Comparator using object attribute in programming language C#.

There are objects with same value for attribute, so duplicate keys occur in the collection.

Complexityclasses for inserting and removing elements to or from sorted datastructure should not be higher than O(log(N)) (noted in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions)) since attribute used for sorting will change very often and list has to be updated with every change to stay consistent.

Complexityclasses for getting all elements in datastructure as list in sorted order should not be higher than O(1).

Options might be C# templates [SortedSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.8), [SortedDictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) or [SortedLists](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.8). All of them fail when inserting or deleting from sorted datastructure if duplicate keys are present.

A workaround might be to use stacked SortedDictionaries as shown below, and aggregate objects with equal key as seperated collections, and sort them by another unique key (ID for example):

```
SortedDictionary<long, SortedDictionary<long, RankedObject>> sPresortedByRank = 
new SortedDictionary<long, SortedDictionary<long, RankedObject>>(new ByRankAscSortedDictionary());

long rank = 52
sPresortedByRank[rank] = new SortedDictionary<long, RankedObject>(new ByIdAscSortedDictionary);
```

Inserting and removing elements from datastructure will work in O(log(N)), what is good. Getting all elements from datastructe as list requires a expensive [Queryable.SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8), which increases complexity for this operation to O(N^2), what is not acceptable.

Current best attemp is to use a primitive [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) and insert and delete using [BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8) to identify indices for inserations and deletions. For insert this gives me worst case complexity O(log(N)). For delete average case complexity O(log(n)) since it duplicate keys will be rare, but O(N) in worst case (all objects with same key). Getting all elements of sorted list will be O(1).

Can someone imagine a better way of managing object collection in sorted datastructure that fits my needs, or is current best attemp the best one in general.

Help and well founded opinions are appreciated. Cookies for good answers of course.

Comment: "Complexityclasses for getting all elements in datastructure as list in sorted order should not be higher than O(1)." - if that is a *new* list, then I don't see how you're going to do better than O(N)

Comment: When you have duplicate keys in a dictionary the object must be a list :  SortedDictionary<long, List<RankedObject>>

Comment: @Richard Wieditz Do you consider using [`C5`](https://github.com/sestoft/C5) library? It contains `TreeBag` collection that satisfies all you requirements. By the way, for primitive `List` the complexity of inserting and removing elements is not O(log(N)). O(log(N)) is only complexity of searching the index where the element must be inserted/deleted. But insertion/deletion itself uses `Array.Copy` to shift elements to insert/delete the element. Therefore the complexity would be O(M), where M <= N.

Comment: There used to be a good set of collections in Wintellect's "Power Collections" library, which includes [OrderedMultiDictionary](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/PowerCollections/blob/master/Source/PowerCollections/OrderedMultiDictionary.cs). This used to be on codeplex, but it's since [been moved to github](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/PowerCollections). May be worth a look. (It's implemented using a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) which is quite efficient.)

Comment: Thank you @Iliar Turdushev for this very useful hint !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Iliar Turdushevs very useful hint:

Do you consider using C5 library? It contains TreeBag collection that satisfies all you requirements. By the way, for primitive List the complexity of inserting and removing elements is not O(log(N)). O(log(N)) is only complexity of searching the index where the element must be inserted/deleted. But insertion/deletion itself uses Array.Copy to shift elements to insert/delete the element. Therefore the complexity would be O(M), where M <= N.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution that meets your requirements it to add tie breaking to your comparator to ensure that there will be no duplicates, and a defined total ordering among all objects.  Then you can just use `SortedSet`.

If you can have an ID in every object, for example, then instead of sorting by "rank", you can sort by (rank,ID) to make the comparator a total ordering.

To find all the elements with a specific rank, you would then use `SortedSet.GetViewBeteen()` with the range of (rank,min_id) and (rank,max_id).